# Converting OpenOffice Impress presentation to video without screen recording

Tags: linux, video, conversion, openoffice, openoffice-impress

How can I convert OpenOffice Impress presentation to video without setting up screen recording? The goal is to have a server that produces a MPEG stream with the presentation. I want to avoid screen recording to avoid having a GUI on that server.

The conversion should either be done with a script (on Linux) or be a very easy to use program, so I could ask the user to convert the presentation to video and the upload it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Flash video natively in LibreOffice which is a fork of OpenOffice so hopefully this applies to OpenOffice too.

Set your slide transitions to automatic (Slide Show > Slide Transition > Advance Slide > Automatically after...)

Export > Save as type: Macromedia Flash (SWF)

Comment: I tried this with LibeOffice and got a swf file that could not be played by VLC. I tried then to convert that file to mpeg2 with ffmpeg and got a very short (31 frames for 88 slides) video with images from the presentation (but no text).

Comment: I would suggest using your web browser to play the files, I realise this is not the best solution, but it may be the easiest to implement.

Comment: Web browser will not produce a MPEG2 stream. The MPEG2 stream is then supposed to go to a device that expects it. If I have to use a web browser, then I might as well just use OO Impress itself with a screen grabber (which I want to avoid).

Comment: FWIW, 9+ years later Flash (SWF) videos are dead and unsupported.